# Html code opened with VSCode shows only two colours

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I am migrating from Eclipse to VSCode and installed several extensions for enhancing html view.
But my .html sources are shown in only two colours.
Is any way to view that in a better way, with more colours? at least with one color for html tags, other for html attributes, other for values, other for texts...

.html example:[image: html example]

.vue example:[image: vue example:]

Comment: what extensions do you have installed? Especially have you installed a highlighter for vue?

Comment: Did you install any themes

Comment: Yes, I have several extensions installed and themes

Comment: Installed and *enabled*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BONRL.png)
Theme by default, you need to disable installed extensions related to theme

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your answer so that it can be read on all devices, edited, copied as text, and found through search. As it stands now, your image makes it hard to view and use your answer. See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.